# Android SDK command line not working on mac

Tags: android, bash, command-line

I have my ADT folder at /Users/username/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/ and I am trying to set the bash_profile file to work with it because whenever I type "android" or "adb" into the terminal, it returns "-bash: android: command not found".  Right now, my .bash_profile (which is stored at /Users/username/) looks like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=/Developer/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

After each time I update the file to try something else, I save it and then type "source .bash_profile" into the terminal to refresh the file.  Is it possible that I should be using a command?

I have gone through numerous tutorials on Stack Overflow and other sites, but none of them are working.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What do you see if you type `echo $PATH` ?  Can you invoke those tools if you specify the full pathname of the executable, or might there be a permission issue or path typo as well?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Here's the output:`nicks-mbp:~ nick$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/nick/bin:/Developer/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702//tools:/Developer/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702//platform-tools`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `ANDROID_HOME` doesn't match the path that you say your ADT folder is located at.  Try changing it to:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: Oh, right.  Duh.  I changed ANDROID_HOME, but it still doesn't solve the problem.  Here's the output when I echo the $PATH: `nicks-mbp:~ nick$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/nick/bin:/Users/nickstigsell/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702//tools:/Users/nickstigsell/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702//platform-tools`

Comment: Take out the backslash at the end of the `ANDROID_HOME` variable, and see if that does it. I've edited my answer

Comment: I removed the trailing slash on line 2: but that doesn't work either. Here's the echo $PATH: `nicks-mbp:~ nick$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/nick/bin:/Users/nickstigsell/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/tools:/Users/nickstigsell/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/platform-tools`

Comment: I notice that your username seems to be different at different points in the path: `/Users/nick/bin` and `/Users/nickstigsell ...`. Which one is your home directory located at?

Comment: It's located at "nick".  I mistakenly typed "nickstigsell" because that's the directory name on my other computers.  I've updated the ANDROID_HOME link but it still doesn't work. `nicks-mbp:~ nick$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/nick/bin:/Users/nick/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/tools:/Users/nick/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/platform-tools`

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /Users/nick/Developm‌​ent/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/platform-tools/adb` (or substitute whatever you put in your $PATH most recently)

Comment: Usually the way the adt-bundle is laid out there is a sdk/ folder that contains the commands you're looking for, try adding /sdk to the end of the `ANDROID_HOME` variable

Comment: Yes, find the tools and test them with full paths from the command line, *then* update your path.

Comment: The output was that the file doesn't exist.  I looked at the file path in Finder and then I realized that I was missing the /sdk directory.  Therefore, this is the correct .bash_profile: `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/nick/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Comment: Is everything working now then? If so accept the answer so that people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the shell you are using is ksh or bash? I had same problem but after changing from ksh to bash,it worked every time! refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36220914/1802348) answer