# Setting environment variables in Yosemite

Tags: bash, environment-variables, osx-yosemite

What is the proper way to modify environment variables like PATH in Yosemite?

This is this question [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x) but specifically for yosemite since it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried editing `~/.bash_profile`?

Adding a line like this to `bash_profile` ought to do it:

> export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

Comment: That doesn't work in Yosemite unfortunately. Take a look at the linked post for more.

Comment: Works on my Yosemite. Did you run `source ~/.bash_profile` after modifying?

Comment: It depends on your shell. Bash shell is the default, but if you use Zsh or Ksh, setting `.bash_profile` won't do anything.  It also depends on the Terminal application you're using. The default `Terminal.app` makes all new windows a login shell. Others might make each just a new shell which means that `.bash_profile` isn't executed. You may have to log out and log back into your Mac to see the change in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: He has the `bash` tag so that's what I'm working with. Hasn't given much info about Terminal or if in fact he needs the variables for terminal or for access by some other app

Answer (score 2):

What shell are you using? I'm assuming you're using the default Bash shell. There's also Csh, Ksh, and Zsh.

The `Terminal.app` on Mac OS X by default starts a new *login* shell each time a window is open. This means that `$HOME/.bash_profile` or `$HOME/profile` is always executed when you open a new terminal window. You can set particular defaults in here. For example, I set `PS1` and `set -o vi`.

> **NOTE**: This may not be the case if you're using other Terminal apps like `xterm`. These open new terminal windows as just new shells. This means that you may not see the changes made in `.bash_profile` until you log out and log back in.
>
> You can try editing `$HOME/.bashrc` and see if that helps.
>
> #### What about other shells?
>
> If you're using Kornshell (`ksh`), you need to edit the `$HOME/profile` and not `$HOME/.bash_profile`. If you're using Zshell (`zsh`), you're on your own. It's too wacky to describe here. Read the manpage for `zsh` and search for `ZDOTDIR`.

When you run a shell script, the `$HOME/.bashrc` is executed. Most people put something like this in their `.bash_profile`, so their `.bashrc` settings are included in a new terminal window:

```
[[ -x $HOME/.bashrc ]] && source "$HOME/.bashrc"
```

Some people set things they want to be set when they run a shell script, for example `export $PS4="\$LINENO> "`.

The `$PATH` is a bit different. You can set it in `.bash_profile` (I would not set it in `.bashrc`), But, Mac OS X has an automated why on how systemwide paths are set. A file called `/etc/paths` is used to set the default path for all users using either Bash or Kornshell via the `/usr/libexec/path_helper` program.

On my Mac, I set my `$PATH` to:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/share/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$HOME/bin
```

When I install programs, I usually install them under `/opt` when possible. Then, I link their binaries (where ever they're placed) to `/usr/local/bin`. This way, I don't have to keep building my PATH. Plus, it allows me to override system defaults. For example, `/usr/bin/git` is at 1.9.3. while my installed `/usr/local/bin/git` is at version 2.2.1.

One thing you should not do is modify `/etc/profile` because changes there may be replaced on OS X upgrades.

Comment: Could you clarify on how you make sure that the most recent `git` is run before the apple-git?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with environment variables set and accessed from within /bin/bash or /bin/sh, but with envars that should be set for programs NOT executed from the shell; i.e. normal apps executed from the dock or Finder.

After finally getting things right with launchctl in Mavericks, Apple is in the process of changing things again. The useful subcommands of launchctl are now labelled as **"legacy subcommands"**, some of which are no longer supported.  That leaves a question mark over the others.

In any case, the most important subcommands are still available for now.

launchctl allows for the setting of the overall environment in which user processes execute.  It appears that the overall user environment is inherited by all Terminal processes; i.e. all setenv variables are exported. It's a bit tricky to confirm that. In any case, you will still need your .profile and .bashrc to define functions and aliases, which are not supported by launchctl.

I go to some lengths to ensure that all of my launchctl vars are also defined in my profile.  This enables me to set up the same environment on remote or VM linux systems, with a few minor tweaks.

Al of my setup is described [in this blog post](http://codepulsive.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x.html) .

Answer (score 0):

following solution worked for me.

1. Open Terminal
2. Click on Terminal Menu at right upper corner.
3. click on Preferences
4. Click on General
5. Change Shell open with to command and put /bin/bash in text box.

[image]

Now whatever configuration you do in ~/.bash_profile takes effect. Previously you were not using bash(were using ksh) that is why it was not reading .bash_profile.